# In terms what is the meaning of some Chrome Dev Tools key words

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I have working on performance improvement of our app. I am new to working performance side. For tracking performance I have using chrome dev tool. While I taking record of my app render by using Performance panel I have seeing some keywords. But I don't know those meanings.

For example,

1. Recalculate Style
2. Composite Layers
3. Layout
4. Update Layer Tree
5. Paint
6. etc...

And give some tips to track performance of my page.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?

Comment: Please read [Why is 'Can someone help me' not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Google provides documentation on improving performance that should explain these: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the DevTools docs. We could probably do a better job at defining each of these terms, so I don't think the downvotes are warranted with this question (its current vote score is -2).

Here's a good resource. Each of the terms is defined in the "The Flow Of Things" section.

https://aerotwist.com/blog/the-anatomy-of-a-frame/

Comment: Thanks @Kayce you only person who helps me.